# python local varivble available area

Tags: python

I know that this code can work.

```
def mom_func():
    temp = 0

    def son_func() :
        a = temp
```

and then why this code cannot work ?

```
def mom_func():
    temp = 0

    def son_func() :
        a = temp
        temp = 1
```

error message is `Unresolved reference 'temp'`

```
def mom_func():
    temp = 0

    def son_func() :
        a = temp
        print(a)

    son_func()
```

this code can work print '0'
and when i have set temp to '7', then code printed '7' !

Comment: In Python, when you assign a value to a variable inside a function, Python assumes that variable is local to the function, even if it has the same name as a variable in the outer scope.

Comment: When you modify a variable within a function, it makes that variable local to that function.  To modify a variable in a containing function, you need to declare it `nonlocal`.  To modify a global variable within a function, you need to declare it `global`.

Comment: thank you all ! 'nonlocal' is what i look for !

Answer (score 0):

```
def mom_func():
    temp = 0

    def son_func() :
        a = temp
        temp = 0
        print(a)

    son_func()
```

Here python assumes that **temp** is a **local** variable inside '**son**' function, since it is assigned a new value (**temp = 0**) inside this function. So when you try to access its value before you assign it to 0 (**temp = 0**) inside the '**son**' function you are getting an '**UnboundLocalError**' as it remains **unassigned** before you write **temp = 0** in the next line and raises an error.

To remove this error and access the temp variable from the '**mom**' fucntion you have to assign the temp variable as **nonlocal** inside the **'son'** function so that python won't assume it as local variable after we assign its value to 0 inside the **'son'** function

```
def mom_func():
    temp = 0

    def son_func() :
        nonlocal temp
        a = temp
        temp = 0
        print(a)

    son_func()
```

I hope this would answer your question. Please reply back if you have any more doubt.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, and was marked as such (but not yet closed) long before you posted this answer.